# How to save latex formula image to a folder in Asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, latex

I am using latex for using formula in my project. Here is my code

```js
 EqEditor.embed('editor', '');
 var a = new EqTextArea('equation', 'testbox');
 EqEditor.add(a, false);
```

```css
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://latex.codecogs.com/css/equation-embed.css" />
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/js/eq_config.js"></script>

<div id="editor"></div>
<br />
<br />
<textarea id="testbox" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<img id="equation" />
```

Now I want, after making formula When I click submit button, the formula should be save to a folder in my project with some name such as formula.png
Please help me, either using javascript or c#

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or simple make a workable example here in SO. I will try to edit your question.

Comment: hi sir Thanks for your reply. Here is the working demo
http://www.hotelkalika.com/formula.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick solution. It uses an URL and takes param and produces image.

E.g. If I want to save "A + B = C", then you can follow these steps to produce image programatically.

1. Encode that string, like this - `var k = encodeURI("a + b = c");` . value of k will be equal to `a%20+%20b%20=%20c`.
2. Use that `k` in `url = "http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?" + k`. So that will equal to `http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?a%20+%20b%20=%20c`.
3. You can save that remote URL image to server using following code -

   ```
   using( System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
   {
       wc.DownloadFile("http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?a%20+%20b%20=%20c", @"D:\a.gif"); // replace a.gif with actual file path, that will saved in server.
   }
   ```

Comment: Dear sir
I tried to make it but not able to do it. Please can you make it for me.
Please it will be a great help.

Comment: Yes sir
It worked, Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooo much
You solved my big problem